# jQuery's if $('#foo').is(':hidden') and $('#foo').slideUp() not working when "display: none !important"?

Tags: jquery

This one works:

> http://jsfiddle.net/fGnL7/3/

using

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  if ($("div:first").is(":hidden")) {
    $("div").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    $("div").slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

but if for some reason, the element is made `display: block` by some framework (by Compass/Blueprint's `+clearfix`), so
I used

```
display: none !important
```

to make it not show on page at first, and then the code will not work.

> sample: http://jsfiddle.net/fGnL7/4/

I also tried adding `$("div").css({display: 'block'});` or even `$("div").css({display: 'block !important'});` before it called `slideDown()` and it doesn't work either.

> sample: http://jsfiddle.net/fGnL7/7/

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `overflow: auto;` on the parent of the `<div>` elements you're sliding down instead of the clearfix solution you're currently using.  This isn't really a scripting issue...but a style one.

As an aside, your demos aren't the appropriate way to use jsfiddle and can introduce several errors...the content in the upper left is already inside a `<body>` tag when it renders.  [Instead your examples should look like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/A4GgB/1/) (also note the use of [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)).

Answer (score 1):

`!important` gives *infinite* specificity for a CSS rule, you will not be able to override it.

I suggest not binding your slide behavior on the home page in order to achieve what you want. That would also make the *progressive enhancement* gods happy.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `!important` rule takes precedence over everything! That, and the fact that when the `slide` functions are used, jQuery automatically give the elements a non-`!important` style `display: block`, wiping out your `display: block !important` and causing the styles defined in the `style` tag to take precedence.

The easy workaround is to not use `!important`. The hard one is to hack into the jQuery source and add in a `!important` into the style added to elements that are been slid.

Comment: the problem is I have to use `!important`

Comment: @動靜能量 - why do you *have* to use it? It sounds like you should fix whatever the other issues is, e.g. `clearfix`, there are alternative methods for handling floats.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the height:0 first then remove attribute styles and do regular slideDown/slideUp stuff. should work!

ie: selector.css('height','0').attr('style','').slideUp('slow')